# Why `apt-file list msttcorefonts` returns nothing?

Tags: apt

Why `apt-file list msttcorefonts` returns nothing? Shouldn't it list files that are gonna be installed?

Comment: Are you running this on Ubuntu? This is a virtual package.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I ran this on Ubuntu. Interesting, virtual pacakge. I read the install log again and see `Note, selecting 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' instead of 'msttcorefonts'`, never seen this kind of "redirection"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft TrueType Fonts cannot be distributed, so there is a script to download and install these fonts. The package msttcorefonts is a virtual package just to indicate the fonts have been installed

See the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package for more details.